# space in the file path of batch script

Tags: batch-file

[image]

I wrote batch script for my project, as the path contains space, it's not working.
Could you please help me?

```
@ECHO OFF
REM  The below command will look for the size of file on the server and inform the user if scheduler is down.

setlocal
set nl=^& echo.

set file="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Zoom\Support\CptControl.exe"
set maxbytesize=0

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% EQU %maxbytesize% (echo WARNING !!! %nl%Scheduler File is ^= %maxbytesize% bytes%nl%Please do not process invoices, contact Webcenter Support) else (echo Scheduler File OK)

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 4):

Place quotes out of the value but protecting the asignment

```dos
set "file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Zoom\Support\CptControl.exe"
```

There is no need for `for /f` to read the file size, use a simple `for`. Also
note the quotes not stored in %file% are now included in the command

```dos
FOR %%A IN ("%file%") DO set "size=%%~zA"
```

Just a session capture

[image: Capture of a test code]

The test code

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\Accessories\WordPad.exe"

    echo File to process ------------------------------------------------------------
    echo "%file%"
    echo(

    echo Data from dir command ------------------------------------------------------
    dir "%file%" | findstr /r /c:"^[^ ]"
    echo(

    echo Data from for command ------------------------------------------------------
    for %%a in ("%file%") do (
        echo %%~fa : %%~za
        set "size=%%~za"
    )
    echo Reported size: %size%
    echo(
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me ,Is there any alternate solution for the file path which is having spaces

Comment: @suvarna, sorry but, what `didn't worked` means? **How** did it not work? What is the observed behaviour? How does it differ from the expected behaviour?

Comment: Ideally it has to read the file size and it has to compare with the size which is provided in the logic,if my file path is with out spaces,the logic which I gave in the script is working.

Comment: But If I gave any file path which is having spaces,the cmd window is not opening at all,that means not executing,help me how to give the file path if it is having spaces

Comment: @suvarna, The spaces in the path are those in the `file` variable asignment or are you talking about spaces in the path to the batch file?

Comment: set file="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Zoom\Support\CptControl.exe"--->not working

Comment: @suvarna, this is not the line in my posted code. Check starting quote

Comment: set "file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Zoom\Support\CptControl.exe"
I tried like that too,not working

Comment: @suvarna, I've included a capture of a sample running code. For me the indicated code should work. Try to run your batch from a console to see if there is any error.

Comment: I dnt know how to run from console,i am writing in .txt file and after that iam the changing the extenson of the file to .bat file,and I am clicking on the bat file

Comment: if iam giving 
set filepath="C:\apacsit\test.txt"--.>working

Comment: set file="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Zoom\Support\CptControl.exe"--->not working
set "file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Zoom\Support\CptControl.exe"--->not working

Comment: @suvarna, Press the windows key (on the left of space key) and while pressed press R. This will open the `Run` dialog. type `cmd.exe` and press enter. Now you have a console. type `"x:\where\your\batch\file\is.bat"` and press enter.

Comment: @suvarna, When you dblclick the batch file, if there is an error/problem, the console will close and you will not see anything. Opening the console and running the batch file from command line will allow you to see if there is any error in the execution. This is the way to start debugging the batch file.

Comment: ,If I ran the script in console it is working fine
but I want to give the user as .bat file and he has to double click on that,its our main requirement.could you please help me urgently on this issue

Comment: @suvarna, If I understand you, you now have a bat file and it works without problem when executed from a console. If when clicked it does not work, your problem are not the spaces in the reference to the file. Can you include in your question the updated code you are using?

Comment: I have attached the code which worked for me through console,but the same code didn't worked for me when I double click on the bat file.

Comment: note:i have attached the image in the question itself

Comment: @suvarna, your code can fail  1) if the file does not exist or it is not found (`size`  is not initialized and the `if` fails), but this should not be the case if from command line the file is found, or 2) if in your environment, when you click a batch file the `cmd` extensions are disabled (test changing your `setlocal` line to `setlocal enableextensions`)

Comment: I tried but its not working.Is there any other solution please?

Comment: @suvarna, Sorry, With paths quoted, extensions enabled, with only absolute paths, file existing *and working from the console* I don't see anything in the code to fail.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can set the path as unquoted and then just quote it later:

```
set filepath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Zoom\Support
```

and use it in below in between `%`

```
"%filepath%\CptControl.exe"
```

or file name with spaces

```
"%filepath%\Cpt Control.exe"
```

Comment: @ECHO OFF
REM  The below command will look for the size of file on the server and inform the user if scheduler is down.

setlocal
set nl=^& echo.

set filepath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Zoom\Support
"%filepath%\CptControl.exe"


set maxbytesize=0

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% EQU %maxbytesize% (echo WARNING !!! %nl%Scheduler File is ^= %maxbytesize% bytes%nl%Please do not process invoices, contact Webcenter Support) else (echo Scheduler File OK)

Comment: set filepath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Zoom\Support
"%filepath%\CptControl.exe"